# How to assume IAM role in Salesforce with named credentials?

Tags: apex

I would like to assume an IAM role in Salesforce to make an API callout to an AWS API Gateway endpoint. My understanding of configuring credentials is to use named credentials with AWS v4 signature generation.

AWS v4 requires (in addition to other parameters):

```
AWS Access Key ID: [your key here]
AWS Secret Access Key: [your secret here]
```

But, I only have an IAM role in the format: `arn:aws:iam::*********`

Any suggestions for how I can proceed to setup named credentials using the IAM role but without having access to they access key ID or secret access key?

Thanks!

Comment: Out of the box - no. Instead, the new Named Credentials support [Temporary Access via STS](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.create_edit_external_credential.htm&type=5) creds. That's better than a role. Read more on this in AWS docs.

Comment: Thanks! That's what worked for me.